# Inheriting the inverse gradient of the elements background

Tags: css

Goal: Given a div/menu which has a background gradient, I would like to have the list items in the menu take the inverse of the background gradient for its hover style. By this I do not mean the inverse of the background directly behind the hovered item, but rather the inverse section of the background gradient as if the entire background gradient had been rotated 180 degrees and the hover gradient was inheriting the section of this inverted background gradient which is directly underneath it.

Basic example with static background for hover.

http://plnkr.co/edit/d2HfMaCxLWUVBGtdhhXv?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really hard question, I think

The best solution I could find:

```
.menu-back {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lavender, gray);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.menu-back ul {
  background: inherit;
  background-size: 0px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.menu-back li:hover {
  background-image: inherit;
  background-origin: -100px 0px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 280px;
  background-origin: initial;
}
.menu-back a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu-back li:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 0px -12em;
}
.menu-back li:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 0px -11em;
}
.menu-back li:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: 0px -9.5em;
}
.menu-back li:nth-child(4) {
  background-position: 0px -4.8em;
}
.menu-back li:nth-child(5) {
  background-position: 0px -2.4em;
}
```

Involves a scaleY(-1) in the menu, to get he background reversed there.

The ul inside the menu is reversed again, to get everything looking ok.

To make the background of the menu inheritable by the li, I need to make the inheritance chain and inherit it too in the ul. Since the ul is reversed again, I set its background size to zero (to hide it).

The less elegant part comes in the li themselves. To make the correct part of the background show, I need to set the background position element by element.

But, at least it works:

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKvVe/)