# CSS: Repeat a linear gradient inversely

Tags: html, css, repeat, linear-gradients

Is there a way to have every alternating repeat of a gradient background go inverse?  At the moment I have the following CSS:

```css
html {
  background: white; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, white); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(blue, white); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(blue, white); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(blue, white); /* Standard syntax */

  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body
    Hello world
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently it goes from blue to white top to bottom but as I scroll down it repeats again from blue to white Eg. `blue->white; blue->white; blue->...` .  I would like it to go from `blue -> white -> blue -> white ->...` .

Comment: why not do something like background: linear-gradient(blue, white, blue); and adjust from this ?

Comment: Here is something similar. I understand you have that background and at some action, you want the inverse effect, isn't it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318534/inheriting-the-inverse-gradient-of-the-elements-background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) to achieve it as follows:

```css
html {
  background: white;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(blue, white 100vh, white 100vh, blue 200vh);
  height: 1980px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the height:100%; from body and check it

or check this website to make your page prettier [http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have that background and at some action, you want the inverse effect. For this you can use `transform: scaleY(-1)`. You can use the gradient in a pseudo-element, in `:before{}` to prevent child element from inheriting parent styles.

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.div1 {
  background: white; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, white); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(blue, white); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(blue, white); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(blue, white); /* Standard syntax */
  background-size: cover;
}

.div2 {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
 <body>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div1 div2"></div>
</body>
```